# How to order by date and month in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like below

```
     mdate
---------------
    14 Apr
    13 Apr
    05 Oct
    01 May
    19 Jun
```

But I am not getting any solutions how can I do that.

And I need to order that data like bellow

```
     mdate
---------------
    13 Apr
    14 Apr
    01 May
    19 Jun
    05 Oct
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM ord_det WHERE mstatus != 'Completed' AND live_status = 'Live' AND public!= 'Hide' ORDER BY LEFT(mdate , 2) ASC, STR_TO_DATE(mtime, '%l:%i %p' ) ASC
```

Comment: You should use date data type. Then order by date would be really easy

Comment: Yeah I can easily do that. But the problem is that there is so many data, and if I change it to date format it will be a mass. Depending on that I have to change many of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
order by str_to_date(concat(mdate, ' 2000'), '%d %b %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your query please, I would love to edit it. You'll just need to add an Order By

Like this:

```
order by Year(orderDate),month(OrderDate)
```

Which looks like this in a query context:

```
SELECT     { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) } AS MonthName, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
FROM         [Order]
WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) }, MONTH(OrderDate), YEAR(OrderDate)
order by Year(orderDate),month(OrderDate)
```

Comment: There is no OrderDate in the table. There are month names.

Comment: It's an 'example' because no query was provided at the time, read please :)

Comment: Example of what? If you want the OP to provide a query you can ask it in the comments. Also the question is tagged MySql but your code looks like tsql.

Comment: @Bruno I think it won't work. I provided my query. If it worked it will be too much helpful

Comment: @Bruno it's not a datetime value data.